# Add Material Design Library In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm very very new to Android Studio, and I can't understand how to use the Android Design Library, can someone help me guiding me in each passage? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you build.gradle, add the dependency like:

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
... 
}
```

sync your project and start using it.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#design).

Comment: So I write this code, I rebuild the project and I'm done, right?

Comment: yes. comment here if u are stuck at a later point

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Well I actually found a line saying: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1', so I used 24.2.1 even for the design one, but a few lines before it says: buildToolsVersion "24.0.3". Am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes sure. Just use the same versions for all ''com.android.support.*" type libraries.

Comment: to actually use the theme I think I have to reference it into the styles.xml, isn't it? But even if I Re-Builded the project two times, I can only use AppCompact Styles, why?